# Sharing a folder with Nautilus and NTFS external drive gets errors

Tags: network-shares, ntfs, samba

I am trying to share a folder in Lubuntu over a network that's on an external NTFS drive. Due to the system that I have (rotating backup disks) this is probably the second time that the drive would of been mounted. Its manually mounted with a simple (for example)

```
 mount /dev/sdb1 /media/BACKUP
```

On an internal NTFS disk I have successfully setup a network share and can access it. However on the external disk I can't from any other Windows computer. When setting up the share Nautilus said that it needs to change the other's permissions to allow for other users to write. However afterwords its still blank. Changing it to Read and Write just changes back to blank. Chowning the entire /media folder recursively and trying didn't work. Running PCManFM as root and changing didn't work. Adding "public=yes" to smb.conf and restarting didn't work. I'm out of idea's on what to do.

What's weird is that it worked just fine on an internal NTFS disk, so why not the external one?

Any solutions need to be able to managed inside of a gui (preferably Nautilus) as the person managing the machine isn't as tech savvy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to mount it:

`mount -o rw,umask=0,gid=users /dev/sdb1 /media/BACKUP`

by default the mount is owned by root, now owner will be users group

umask will grant access for everybody

Comment: Wow, I forgot about this question. Unfortunately I have already found another solution: Switching to ClearOS. It offers everything I need in a nice and easy to manage interface. +1 though for helping out

Comment: How can I make this mount this way at logon?